# Importing app when using Alembic raises ImportError

Tags: python, import, flask, alembic

I am trying to study how to use alembic in flask, I want to import a method in flask app:

```
tree .
.
├── README.md
├── alembic
│   ├── README
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── env.pyc
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
│       ├── 8f167daabe6_create_account_table.py
│       └── 8f167daabe6_create_account_table.pyc
├── alembic.ini
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── errors.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── 404.html
│       ├── 500.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── index.html
│       └── user.html
├── config.py
├── data.sqlite
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

in **app/__init__.py**:

```
def create_app(config_name):
  app = Flask(__name__)
```

I want to import `create_app` in `env.py`:

```
from app import create_app
```

but the error shows as below when I run the command `alembic upgrade head`:

```
  File "alembic/env.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import create_app
ImportError: No module named app
```

Any idea for this?

Comment: Try change your package(`app`) name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you are trying to run

```
python env.py
```

In this case, your app directory is not in `PYTHONPATH`.

### solution 1

Run the app from parent dir:

```
python alembic/env.py
```

### solution 2

Set the `PYTHONPATH` before running the app

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent/dir python env.py
```

### edit

I read about `alembic`. As @mrorno said, just set the `PYTHONPATH` before running alembic:

```
PYTHONPATH=. alembic upgrade head
```

Comment: I am trying to study how to use alembic in flask, so I run the command: `alembic upgrade head`

Answer (score 7):

`alembic` just tries to load your `env.py` source code. It's not in your package, so it can't access your `app` module.

Use solution 2 @tomasz-jakub-rup suggested, you can execute like

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. alembic upgrade head
```

and you should get your result.

Answer (score 5):

Create file `.env` and insert `PYTHONPATH=.`

Answer (score 0):

Add `prepend_sys_path = .` into `alembic.ini` file like this:

```
[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic
prepend_sys_path = .
```