# I ma trying to use alembic with fastapi and postgres sql but it gives me error that No module named 'database but it existing in the project

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

it gives me this error when I am running the alembic --autogenerate command.
it gives the error that No module name database found but database.py file exist and it gives this error.

this is my env file and an error is occurring due to this file when I am using alembic in this file the from app.models import Base
from app.config import setting files are imported so it gives the error that in these files the database and config module dose not exist but it exist there.
env.py:

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from app.models import Base
from app.config import setting

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", f'postgresql://{setting.database_username}:{setting.database_password}@{setting.database_hostname}:{setting.database_port}/{setting.database_name}')

# config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", 'postgresql://postgres:uxairkhan@localhost/alembic')

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

database.py:
this is the database.py file and in this file it says the config does not exist and the same error occurring in the models.py file also that there is no module database.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
# from config import setting

```
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://<username>:<password>@<ip-address/hostname>/<database-name>'
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f'postgresql://{setting.database_username}:{setting.database_password}@{setting.database_hostname}:{setting.database_port}/{setting.database_name}'

engine  = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False , autoflush=False , bind=engine)
                
Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

ERROR:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC>alembic current
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 588, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 582, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 559, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 543, in current
    script.run_env()
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 563, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 92, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 108, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\alembic\env.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app.models import Base
  File "C:\Users\Muzair\Desktop\FAwithFCC\.\app\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from database import Base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

I search for this error in the documentation and it take 3 days for me but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the full path to the database.py file?

Comment: @GordThompson database.py file is existing in the same folder                                from database import Base                                                                                                        this one library not importing.

Comment: try `from .database import Base`

Answer (score 0):

You have probably initlized alembic in your /app folder, which is not a problem, but cumbersome to handle.
The error originates from the fact that alembic does not generate a package.

To fix your error, you can either delete your alembic folder and reinitlize alembic on the same level your /app folder is located.
By doing so you can checkout the general project structure of the official demo project of fastapi
https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app

or you execute alembic with a set PYTHONPATH pointing to root of you app folder.

```
PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/toyourproject/ alembic revision --autogenerate -m "name"
```

See: [Importing app when using Alembic raises ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821470/importing-app-when-using-alembic-raises-importerror)

You could also fix the error by using os and adding your path to sys

See: https://github.com/grillazz/fastapi-sqlalchemy-asyncpg/blob/main/alembic/env.py